# Server-side includes (SSI) stop working when on https (ssl)

Tags: ssl, https

My server side includes work fine when accessing the website through http, but when trying to access the site securely (which is all set up sweet) they just don't get included.

I'm using the following code in the one file inside my apache2/sites-enabled directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
      Options +Includes
      AddType text/html .htm
      AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .htm
</Directory>
```

Any ideas about where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had only put the above code into the virtualhost section for the ordinary port, not the ssl port.